# change order of grid style (masonry)

Tags: css, grid, masonry

i have a grid style:

```
<div class="masonry">
    <div class="item">10</div>
    <div class="item">9</div>
    <div class="item">8</div>
    <div class="item">7</div>
    <div class="item">6</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">1</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.masonry {
    column-count: 5;
    column-gap: 1em;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.item {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0 1em;
    width: 100%;
}
```

the result is in this picture (items orders by column):
[Current image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FukpR.jpg)
but i want to order items by row.First, fill in the first row, then second row and etc.like this photo [my favorite state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFpYC.jpg)

Comment: if you are wnating a masonry layout then you are best using a js plugin as it is very hard to achieve using pure css

Answer (score -1):

I did with flexbox see below code, I believe this is what you are looking for

```css
.masonry {
    margin-top: 20px;
    display: flex;
     flex-direction: row-reverse; 
     align-items: flex-end;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.item {
    margin: 0 0 1em;
    width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="masonry">
    <div class="item">10</div>
    <div class="item">9</div>
    <div class="item">8</div>
    <div class="item">7</div>
    <div class="item">6</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">1</div>
</div>
```